# State not updating between two useEffect in React in jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using two useEffect for two different redux variables. All is working fine when I run the application in browser but it is not passing jest test because the state is not updating. Following is the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [testString, setTestString] = useState('test');

useEffect(() => {
  setTestString('changed');  
}, [testA]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(testString);  
}, [testB]);
```

I am passing testA and testB when writing in jest and these effects are running in correct order. But when it prints in the second useEffect testString is not updated it is still showing values as 'test'. Any idea where I am going wrong in this?

Comment: "test" is the correct value for the first render. Are you saying it doesn't render again with the new value?

Comment: Even for the first render should not it print values as changed because when it got to the testA useEffect it updated the value and yeah even for second render it is not updating the value and also I am confused how it is working in browser but not in jest tests?

Comment: This is caused by the fact that setTestString will set the state asynchonously and how react runs the useEffects. It will run through, find and run the first useEffect, it will then find and run the second useEffect in the same render pass before the value has been updated.

Comment: @JacobSmit I am curious how it works when application is run in browser. And also what will be the way to achieve that in jest then?

Answer (score 1):

In the first render, `testString` is set to "test". After the render, the effects run in order.

The first one runs and calls `setTestString`, but this does not change `testString`. `testString` is a `const` so it couldn't be changed even if we wanted it to. The purpose of `setTestString` isn't to change the value in local variables, but to tell react to rerender the component. When that render happens, new local variables will be created with new values, but your first render doesn't have access to those future values.

Then the second effect runs. The `testString` in its closure is the `testString` from the first render, so it logs out "test".

As for your question about the jest tests, I'd need to see what your test code is to comment on that.

Comment: So after some trial and error an interesting thing I can see.. If in jest while creating the mock store I pass testB in the json data then the value is not changing and if I don't pass testB then value is printed with first initial value then the changed value.